# Acquiring ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of DIVs that I wish to be able to identify when the mouse is clicked over them. The following is a reduction of the HTML code I am currently using:

```
<div id="1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0;"></div>
<div id="10" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0;"></div>
<div id="11" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0;"></div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 450px; left: 0;">
    <button onclick="sendAnswer()">Answer</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

There are (currently) 24 such DIVs, using binary notation as their IDs.

I have added an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + event.target.id;
});
```

So, I get the word Hello popping up but not the ID of the DIV I am clicking on top of.

I have been exploring suggestions elsewhere but to no avail.

To clarify, each of the binary ID dIVs are assigned a random image, which I eventually intend to make draggable onto a grid. I had them draggable already but the code was cluttered, clunky and intermittent. I have another idea but it requires that I identify the element just clicked on.

Comment: you missed `event` to pass to the event listener callback function.

Comment: Thanks for this; absolutely right. I have given a little more details below in another comment, but wanted to thank you for your response. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always get the event in listener callback, you can get the id from there like

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + event.target.id;
});
```

```html
<div id="1" >1</div>
<div id="10" >2</div>
<div id="11" >3</div>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did originally have the event in there but I must have removed it during testing! The actual issue turned out to be how I was assigning the image to the div; as an innerHTML image rather than as a backgroundImage. This meant that I had to click on the border of the DIV for my routine to function correctly. As I say, in attempts to get it right I made it more wrong! Without your direction (and that of others) I would have spent even more time in a spiral downwards. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to this

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
alert( event.target.id);
```

});

Comment: This is nothing new from what has already been suggested in the comment and in the answer

Comment: Yes, it was given previously but thanks for responding anyway; you cannot be corrected too many times. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
window.onload=function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('div.foo').forEach(function(e){
   e.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + this.id;
    });
   });
}
```

```html
 <div id="1" class="foo" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0;">1</div>
 <div id="10"  class="foo" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0;">2</div>
 <div id="11"  class="foo" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 0;">3</div>
    
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 0;">
     
        <p id="demo"></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: As stated to another response, I didn't want to have an onClick response for 24 DIVs when only the ID changed. I felt the same with the idea of adding a duplicate class name to all 24 DIVs, which was a solution I pondered for a while. Works beautifully, but just feels 'cluttered' from my perspective. However, yours was working and mine wasn't; so, where's the beauty in that, eh? Hahaha! Again, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Id of the div directly on html like so:

```
Onclick="sendAnswer(this.id)"
```

And the js function like this:

```
function sendAnswer (var x){

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + x;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it helped

Comment: Thanks for this. This was one of the first approaches I undertook but felt that giving 24 DIVs an OnClick response was a bit of overkill when the only difference was the ID of each DIV; hence my desire to reduce this down to a single function that identified the ID and then ran the click/drag code. However, I might be returning to this if my next set of steps fail me. Hahaha! :)